# Handle/disable GNOME RANDR triggers & events

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, xrandr

What is the relationship between `xrandr` and the GNOME display manager (I hesitate to call this `gdm3` because I use `lightdm`; rather, I am referring to the way monitors and multiple displays are managed).

I found this file

```
cat /home/user/.config/monitors.xml

<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-0</connector>
          <vendor>SAM</vendor>
          <product>SAMSUNG</product>
          <serial>0x01000601</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-5</connector>
          <vendor>HDM</vendor>
          <product>Capture      </product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

As I was writing this I came across https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/RandR#Storage_of_RANDR_configurations which looks rather outdated but pretty much exactly the type of information I am looking for (though it would be much better if there was documentation discussing how to manipulate the event triggers and handling).

Does the GNOME display manager still use `xrandr` to detect events and make changes? If so, how can I disable this, manipulate triggers and handling, etc?

Thanks in advance